# Reduce .git folder size: Jenkins edition

Tags: git, jenkins, diskspace

I'm using Jenkins to pull a specific branch from a git repository. The .git folder is approximately 5x the size of the project that it's pulling!  I tried `git gc --aggressive --prune` but the problem persists.

I'm never going to push from Jenkins back into the repository. I just need to quickly check for changes to the repo, and when any are found grab those changes and build the project. If it's an issue with history, obviously I can do without.

I'm specifically using the git plugin, so methods tailored to that would be ideal since that's going to do the initial fetch every time. If I have to run commands after the fetch, I'll do it.

Comment: Do you have lots of changing binary files in your git repository? They will naturally not compress as well as source code. I am working with a git repo that has 12 years of history. The object db is still not much larger than the contents of a checkout.

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer is: ignore the size of the .git folder. When you are pulling in changes, only the changes will be copied, not the full git repo. (Unless you are deleting the jenkins workspace before build, but that would not be a good idea, because it would force your job to make a full clone on every build.)

If you worry about getting a clean build, check the box: Clean after checkout. It makes Jenkins run git clean" before build.

If you worry about disk space, just get a big disk. Or if you are using a small SSD, install postbuild plugin and run "git clean -fxd" from a postbuild step to clean up the workspace.

If none of the above work for you, then all you can do is wait. Partial git checkout support might become better in the future. Or you could use Subversion or some other non-distributed version control system. Pretty much all the distributed systems depend on having the full history available.

Comment: That's a bummer, but seeing that Systems could dynamically grow the partition of the disk in question it will probably have to do!

Comment: Using option "Clean before checkout" runs the following commands: `git reset --hard` and `git clean -fdx`